# How to create a light highlight in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, lighting-effects

I have the following image created in Gimp.

[image]

I'd like to create a similar image in Inkscape. What I want to happen is to have a bright light source and I want this light source to brighten the circles having the most intense effect at the edge of the blue circle.

In Gimp I'm able to achieve this by having a white to black gradient as separate layer on top and setting the blend mode of that layer to `addition` (using the technique in this tutorial: http://gimp-tutorials.net/gimp-glow-effect)

How can I achieve a similar effect in Inkscape?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use gradients in Inkscape?

Comment: @Scott: No, but how do you get the gradient to go across all three objects?  And how do you get the gradient to merely lighten the objects rather than change their color?  I have no idea, hence my question

Comment: Can' you instead of adding a "layer" just add another object with a white to transparent gradient on top of your circles?

Comment: @Takkat: possibly but the resulting image needs to be exported to a transparent png.  It seems like with a white to transparent gradient on top, that the white that goes over the background would show through which would not be what I want.  If there's a way to do what you suggest but only over the surface of the objects then that sounds like it could work.  Also I just mentioned gradient because that's how I did it in Gimp. Maybe in Inkscape a gradient isn't even the right tool.  Maybe there is some other technique to have a light source.

Comment: @Takkat: thanks your suggestion was enough for me to get the job done.  In my case I duplicated the object on another layer and added the white-to-transparent gradient on that object.  Although I'd still be interested in an alternative solution in the case where the objects are greater in number and/or more complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reproduce the effect you made in Gimp with Inkscape I took the following steps:

1. Create filled circles and make them a group

   [image]
2. Create a large circle with the gradient circular fill (here black for illustration)

   [image]
3. Duplicate the group of colored circles to then create a unified path (*Path > Union*)

   [image]
4. Select this new path and the gradient circle to **cut out the path intersection** (*Path > Intersection*)

   > At this point I added a canvas and changed the gradient fill from black to white.
5. Move the gradient until happy

   [image]

After grouping the gradient object and the coloured circle group we will finally have a new object resembling your Gimp original:

[image]

---

Side note: for more fancy or realistic effects we may also want to try out some of the inbuilt filters to get many interesting effects (below I applied *Filters > Bevels > Deep color plastic*)

[image]

Comment: I'm curious how do you feel having the separate circle with a gradient (as you have done in this answer) compares to just adding a gradient fill to the unified path object?

Comment: @User: yeah it would be the same. The gradient can freely be chosen on the path intersection object (which does not need to come from a circle but could also be any other object). It was done here merely for illustrating the basic principle behind this.